# hibernate One-to-many association : subselect or eager

Tags: hibernate, grails, lazy-loading, eager

In a grails application, i have a relationship that is by default lazy:

```
class Author{
    String name
    static mapping = {
         books lazy:false
    }
}
```

I have a criteria API query that fetches the Authors. 
When i run the query

```
Author.createCriteria().list{
    eq("name", "John")
}
```

i have N+1 subselects for each Author.

My second approach is to eager fetch the books just like this:

```
Author.createCriteria().list{
    eq("name", "John")
    fetchMode("books", FetchMode.JOIN)
}
```

In this case, the N+1 select problem does not appear, however i have a JOIN query.

Which approach is better in terms of performance and optimization ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant by default `eager` instead of `lazy` in the first line of the question.

**POINT TO REMEMBER**
When associations are included in criteria query, they are by default **eagerly** fetched.

In your case you do not need the mapping `books lazy:false` in `Author`.
In terms of *optimization* I would vouch for the below approach:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    static mapping = {
         //books lazy:false (DO NOT NEED)
    }
}

class Book {
    String bookName
    //set belongsTo if you need bi-directional one-many
    //books gets cascade deleted when author is deleted
    //static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}

//Bootstrap
def author1 = new Author(name: "Dan Brown")
def book1 = new Book(bookName: "Da Vinci Code")
def book2 = new Book(bookName: "Angels And Demons")
def book3 = new Book(bookName: "Inferno")

[book1, book2, book3].each {author1.addToBooks(it)}
author1.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

//Criteria
Author.createCriteria().list{
    eq("name", "Dan Brown")
    books{
       //books are eagerly fetched by default using inner join. No need to specify FetchMode.
    }
}
```

In terms of performance I would **not** go with the above approach if I have each Author who has wrote 20000 blogs(replace books with blogs). Eagerly fetching 20000 blogs for `n` authors will be a performance hit. In this case I would go for lazy fetch (N + 1) route and try to filter out blogs as per my requirement. Something like below:

```
def author = Author.findByName("Dan Brown")
def books = author.books
//Assume you have a field publishedYear in Book
def booksReleasedIn2013 = author.books.findAll{it.publishedYear == 2013} 
def booksReleasedBefore2013 = author.books.findAll{it.publishedYear < 2013} 

assert "Inferno" in booksReleasedIn2013*.bookName
assert "Angels And Demons" in booksReleasedBefore2013*.bookName
```

If you do not have such(blogs case) case, then I would use the example cited above for both *optimization* and *performance*.